# Android check if network connection exists not always working

Tags: android, broadcast, android-networking

I copied that from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009133/2715720):

```
public static boolean isOffline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected(); // netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
}
```

If the screen is on and I'm using the device it works correct. But sometimes if the device is sleeping it returns that the device is offline.

I have a broadcast wich calls the same method later - then it is working (during a bug it is currently right afterwards).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your device MarshMellow?

Comment: yes it is android 6.1

Comment: The network connection optimization is a new feature in MarshMellow. Your application should work in pre-marshmellow devices.

Comment: unfortunately no - some testers reported me that it doesn't work either